# Geb: Web element locator for multi element navigator

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, ui-automation, geb

I have  a html page with an element called **Student** and it has multiple rows like below:

```
Student: Foo Bar
         Class X
         Section A
```

I was able to locate the Student element using XPath like this: `//b[contains(text(),'Student')]` but I want to extract the same thing using jquery selector and extract it's child elements like `Foo Bar, Class X and Section A` using jquery Selector

I tried something like below but it didn't work:
`student(wait: true) { $('b', text: contains('Student:')).parent().parent()`

Here is how the html looks:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="left" height="25" class="SubSectionTitle" style=""><b style="">&nbsp;Student Information</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="top" class="Label" rowspan="3"><b style="">Student:</b></td>
   <td style="">Foo Bar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Class X</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Section A</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear because you did not add a test, so I cannot see which condition you are trying to check. Your fragmentary information about XPath vs. CSS selectors does not help either, the two even contradict each other: One searches for "Student" without trailing colon, the other for "Student:", but trying to navigate up the DOM element nesting hierarchy. Nowhere did you clearly state which element you are trying to select. The sub section title? One of the other table rows (which one)? All rows? I could probably answer each of these question, if I only knew which one.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback to my answer in order to close this question which is still listed as unanswered. Thank you. I would subsequently delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is unclear, I am showing you several options:

**HTML page `src/test/resources/page-q66129162.html`:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left" height="25" class="SubSectionTitle" style=""><b style="">&nbsp;Student Information</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="Label" rowspan="3"><b style="">Student:</b></td>
        <td style="">Foo Bar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Class X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Section A</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Geb test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q66129162

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import org.openqa.selenium.By

class MultiElementNavigatorIT extends GebSpec {
  static url = this.getResource("/page-q66129162.html").toString()

  def test() {
    given:
    go url

    when:
    def xp = $(By.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Student:')][1]"))

    then:
    xp.text() == "Student:"
    xp.parent().text() == "Student:"
    xp.parent().parent().text() == "Student: Foo Bar"
    xp.parent().parent().parent().text() == " Student Information\nStudent: Foo Bar\nClass X\nSection A"

    when:
    def nav = $('b', text: contains('Student:'))

    then:
    nav.text() == "Student:"
    nav.parent().text() == "Student:"
    nav.parent().parent().text() == "Student: Foo Bar"
    nav.parent().parent().parent().text() == " Student Information\nStudent: Foo Bar\nClass X\nSection A"
  }
}
```

Or if you like it a bit more compact:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q66129162

import geb.spock.GebSpec
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import spock.lang.Unroll

class MultiElementNavigatorIT extends GebSpec {
  static url = this.getResource("/page-q66129162.html").toString()

  @Unroll
  def "select by #selectorType"() {
    given:
    go url
    def selector = selectorClosure()

    expect:
    selector.text() == "Student:"
    selector.parent().text() == "Student:"
    selector.parent().parent().text() == "Student: Foo Bar"
    selector.parent().parent().parent().text() == " Student Information\nStudent: Foo Bar\nClass X\nSection A"

    where:
    selectorType | selectorClosure
    "XPath"      | { $(By.xpath("//b[contains(text(),'Student:')][1]")) }
    "CSS"        | { $('b', text: contains('Student:')) }
  }
}
```

If your question was rather how to select from a multi element navigator, you can use something like `myNavigator.first()` or `myNavigator[0]`.